# Show that the roots of the equation

Tags: polynomials, roots, quadratics

Show that the roots of 
$$(a^2-bc)x^2+2(b^2-ca)x+(c^2-ab)=0$$
will be equal, if either $b=0$, or $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=0$.

My attempt:
Comparing above equation with $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$, we get,
$$A=(a^2-bc)$$
$$B=2(b^2-ca)$$
$$C=(c^2-ab)$$
According to question
$$B^2-4A.C=0$$
$$[2(b^2-ca)]^2-4(a^2-bc)(c^2-ab)=0$$
On solving a few steps, I got:
$$4b^4-8b^2ca+4a^3b+4bc^3-4ab^3c=0$$

Comment: Recheck your calculations at the last step.

Comment: @dxiv, Is there any alternative method for this question?

Comment: I'd be surprised if you found anything simpler than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit: Thanks fonfonx for pointing out the mistake

The discriminant $D$ is equal to $$4b^4-8b^2ca+4a^3b+4bc^3-4ab^2c$$

Let's factorize the discriminant:

$$4b(b^3-2abc+a^3+c^3-abc)$$

which is equal to

$$4b(b^3+a^3+c^3-3abc)$$

Hence if $b=0$ or $(b^3+a^3+c^3-3abc)=0$, the discriminant is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in the discriminant. It is

$$4b^4-8b^2ca+4a^3b+4bc3-4ab^{\color{red}{2}}c=4b\cdot(b^3-3abc+a^3+c^3)$$